# Angular2 refresh page after passing object to component

Tags: angular

I am trying to refresh a page to display a selected value form a table in another compontent's template without success, the following code is some made up code that will hopefully make the issue clear.
So i have 2 components:
TableComponent which displays a list of heroes.
Screen which displays the selected hero's details, this is a child of TableComponent
The goal is that, when you click on an hero's name from the table, the details would display in the 'screen' component. so the code:

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'heroes-table',
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  private tableData: Array<Object>; 
  //The component that will display the hero's details
  private screen: Screen;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tableData = ['Windstorm', 'Bombasto', 'Magneta', 'Tornado'];
    this.screen = new Screen();
  }

//Function called when a hero is selected from the table view
public onSelect(hero: Object){
  this.screen.setHero(hero);
 }
}
```

The table:
//heroes table:

```
<div class="table-row-group" *ngFor="let hero of tableData" [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero" (click)="onSelect(hero)"> 
    <div class="table-row" >
      <div class="table-cell">{{hero}}</div>
    </div>
   //Screen is a child
  <screen></screen>
</div>
```

The screen:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'screen',
})
export class Screen {

  private hero: Object;

  constructor() { }

  public setHero(hero: Object){
    this.incident=incident;
    console.log(this.hero)
  }
}
```

The screen's templatE:

```
//screen table:
<p>
  Current hero:{{hero}}
</p>
```

So when i debug in console, i see that the selected hero is printed in the Screen's `setHero` method, but the screen's view will not refresh, it remains with : Selected her: without displaying anything.
Any advice?

Comment: you can use `@input` decorator to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **`@input`** decorator to get it done.

**@input recieves the data from parent to child compenent**

Send data using,

**`<screen [hero]="hero"></screen>`**

Receive data using,

**`@Input() hero;`**

Use data using,

**`Current hero:{{hero}}`**

**Parent Component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'heroes-table',
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  private tableData: Array<Object>; 
  private screen: Screen;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tableData = ['Windstorm', 'Bombasto', 'Magneta', 'Tornado'];
  }

public onSelect(hero: Object){
  this.hero = hero;
 }
}
```

**Parent HTML:**

```
<div class="table-row-group" *ngFor="let hero of tableData" [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero" (click)="onSelect(hero)"> 
        <div class="table-row" >
          <div class="table-cell">{{hero}}</div>
        </div>
       //Screen is a child
      <screen [hero]="hero"></screen>
</div>
```

Observe **`<screen [hero]="hero"></screen>`**

**Child component:**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'screen',
})
export class Screen {
  @Input() hero;
  constructor() {}
}
```

**Child View:**

```
<p>
  Current hero:{{hero}}
</p>
```